# Detect whether a browser, a tab and which tab amongst all the opened tabs has been closed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How to detect whether a browser has been closed, a tab has been closed and which tab amongst all the opened tabs has been closed ?
Are there any events available to handle each one of the above cases in Angular/Javascript. Any information or sample code will be helpful and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it with `onunload`  and `onbeforeunload` events. But you cannot prevent that event and continue your logic.

But remember, you can still trigger a "Your are leaving the page" confirmation